# Generate all valid binary search trees given a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-search-tree

Hello I am trying to solve the following question on leetcode, [https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-binary-search-trees-ii/].

I know I have access to the solution but I tried solving the problem my way and I am stuck and I would like to know if it is solvable the way I am doing it.
Here is the code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def generateTrees(myrange, n, res = None):
    if res == None:
        res = []
    if myrange == []:
        res.append(None)
        return
    for root in myrange:
        res.append(root)
        generateTrees([i for i in range(root) if i in set(myrange)], n, res) #leftchild
        generateTrees([i for i in range(root+1, n) if i in set(myrange)], n, res) #rightchild
    return res
```

Initially `myrange` is just the list containing the node values, and `n` is the length of `myrange`.

The way I am doing it is a sort of DFS where I loop over the nodes making  each one of them the root once and then I do the same for the left and right subtrees to get all combinations. But the problem I am facing is I can't figure out how to manage `res` to remove elements from it as my recursion backtracks (and make it so `res` only contains valid bst's and then put those in some other list that will be my actual result).

I would like some pointers or even just comments on if you think my approach is valid or bad ..etc.

Comment: Not sure what the order is in the tree output format. The question does not really explain that format. Or is the purpose to output instances of `TreeNode`? Your code never instantiates that class?

Comment: You are right it does not I was trying to solve it by creating a list of lists in the same format they do the example on leetcode when I could have outputed a list of root nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- As you mention, your code only creates one list to which it keeps appending.
- Even if you would fix that, the lists would never come out in the BFS kind of order, which is what the question's example seems to suggest.
- For a chosen root, you need to list all combinations of its possible left subtrees with its possible right subtrees -- a Cartesian product if you wish. This logic is missing in your code.

I would:

- not pass `res` as argument to the recursive function. Just return it, and let the caller deal with it.
- not use ranges, as that only seems to complicate things. The `if i in set(myrange)` seems like an inefficient way to get the overlap between two ranges. I would instead pass the two extremes of the range as separate arguments.
- use the `TreeNode` class to actually create the trees, and deal with generating the required output format later.
- For generating the output format you need a BFS walk through the tree, and this could be implemented as a method on `TreeNode`.

Here is what I think would work:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def breadth_first(self):
        lst = []
        todo = [self]
        while any(todo):
            node = todo.pop(0)
            lst.append(node.val if node else None)
            if node:
                todo.append(node.left)
                todo.append(node.right)
        return lst

def generateTrees(n):
    def recur(start, end): # end is not included
        if start >= end:
            return [None]
        trees = []
        for root in range(start, end):
            lefts = recur(start, root)
            rights = recur(root+1, end)
            # Cartesian product:
            for left in lefts:
                for right in rights:
                    # Start with a new tree, and append to result
                    tree = TreeNode(root)
                    tree.left = left
                    tree.right = right
                    trees.append(tree)
        return trees
    return recur(1, n+1)

# Create the trees as a list of TreeNode instances:
trees = generateTrees(3)
# Convert to a list of lists 
print([tree.breadth_first() for tree in trees])
```